# Docker process for creating image, installing software (while creating image) and starting container

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I have a simple Dockerfile:
`FROM ubuntu
CMD apt-get update; apt-get upgrade;  apt-get  install -y openjdk-8-jdk python2.7 python-pip unzip libaio1 nano tree curl wget alien`

On my host machine (Mac) running this command from the same folder where above Dockerfile is in order to create image:
`docker build . -t my-linux`

That takes a minute or two and then check images created with `docker images`:
`REPOSITORY       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my-linux         latest              f9061de79d89        34 seconds ago      112MB
ubuntu           latest              f975c5035748        2 weeks ago         112MB`

Next, I run (create container) based on image:
`docker run -it my-linux bash`

Tried installed software:
`root@79a49eab5342:/# nano
bash: nano: command not found
root@79a49eab5342:/#`

Why is 'nano' not installed? (and other software too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.

Via [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

So you should use `RUN` instead of `CMD`.

Also, in you Dockerfile you could do:

```
CMD ["bash"]
```

This will automatically execute bash and bring you into the shell, so you don't have to do `-it` when you do a `docker run`. It will bring you straight into the shell.

Comment: Thanks, for catching that :) I think I copied from example Dockerfile but 'RUN' worked.. And thanks for pointing for example for CMD and bash!